# Disable output of "Page x" in tesseract when using stdout as output

Tags: tesseract

I try to use tesseract for OCR of pictures and I would like to disable the somewhat verbose output of the pages tesseract is scanning:

```
:~$ tesseract stdin stdout -l eng txt
Page 1
<ocr output>
```

Is it possible to remove the "Page 1" from the output?

```
:~$ tesseract --version
tesseract 4.0.0-146-gc39a
```

Comment: Try `quiet` option at the end of the command.

Comment: @nguyenq that was quiet right (pun intended). Can you answer the question so I can mark it as answered and you earn some points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `quiet` option at the end of the command.

Comment: Uh... how?  `-quiet`?  If I put it at the very end of the command it still prints the page number.  If I put it before the filenames, it vomits errors at me, saying it can't open stdout, can't find my file, etc.  I don't see "quiet" mentioned in the man page either.

Comment: Another way: add `-c debug_file=/dev/null` somewhere before the input/output params.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant you only wanted to see the OCR'd text then just redirect stderr to null.

```
foo | tesseract - - 2>/dev/null
```

Or of course, to a log file if you so desire.